# After using jquery to set div to display none, how do you slide up the rest slowly?

Tags: jquery, html

If I use jQuery to set a `div` to `display: none;` when a user action has been completed, and at same time the remaining div 'skips' into its place.

Which is what I want, however, how do I achieve this with a nice sliding up motion, rather than just 'shooting' up?

**EDIT**
Have a look at the fiddle, you will see the 'click me', goes straight up without using a nice motion.

http://jsfiddle.net/TfQML/2/

If i add slideUp, it makes it completely dissappear:

http://jsfiddle.net/TfQML/3/

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show what code you're using.

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: you might get answer if you show what you have tried

Comment: @caramba, i have updated with a fiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `slideUp()` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

Update: You can now apply this to your fiddle to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/72CSe/2/

Comment: Aaahhhh i see what you've done, in my latest fiddle i misunderstood the concept. Thank you!